# Remove Observer iOS

Tags: ios, nsnotifications

I want to remove this observer in my code :

```
[self.noteLabel addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"contentSize" options:(NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew) context:NULL];
```

What is the good practice to remove it ?
Thanks

**EDIT**

I want to remove this observer because I need to remove its parentView. Actually it crashes because of this observer. What would be the good practice to remove a subview with an observer ? Thanks for your help.

Comment: When do you know you're finished...

Comment: You should add this observer inside self.noteLabel subclass. Then you remove the observer on dealloc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whenever you want to remove an observer, you just have to use `removeObserver`with the right parameters.

```
[self.noteLabel removeObserver:self forKeyPath:@"contentSize"];
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not completely safe what you've presented. You can use such code:

```
#pragma mark - KVO

static void *_myContextPointer = &_myContextPointer;
- (void)enableObserver:(BOOL)enable onObject:(id)object selector:(SEL)selector {
    NSString *selectorKeyPath = NSStringFromSelector(selector);
    if (enable) {
        [object addObserver:self forKeyPath:selectorKeyPath options:0 context:&_myContextPointer];
    } else {
        @try {
            [object removeObserver:self forKeyPath:selectorKeyPath context:&_myContextPointer];
        } @catch (NSException *__unused exception) {}
    }
}

- (void)observeValueForKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath ofObject:(id)object change:(NSDictionary *)change context:(void *)context {
    if (context != _myContextPointer) {
        [super observeValueForKeyPath:keyPath ofObject:object change:change context:context];

        return;
    }

    [self observerActionForKeyPath:keyPath ofObject:object change:change];
}
```

and ofc such code to handle your observer:

```
- (void)observerActionForKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath ofObject:(id)object change:(NSDictionary *)change {
    NSString *contentSizeKeyPath = NSStringFromSelector(@selector(contentSize));
    if ([keyPath isEqualToString:contentSizeKeyPath]) {
        // do something
    }
}
```

Then you just call it eg:

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];

    [self enableObserver:YES onObject:self selector:@selector(contentSize)];
}

- (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewWillDisappear:animated];

    [self enableObserver:NO onObject:self selector:@selector(contentSize)];
}
```

Via using such code, your app won't crash because you remove observers few times in a row. Also you can't make a typo in your property name and it will dynamically change when you refactor your code. All KVO is in one place.

You can read more about safe KVO on [NSHipster](http://nshipster.com/key-value-observing/) page.

Answer (score 0):

Typically you start observing some key path in `-init` and stop doing so in `-dealloc`.

I would unregister yourself in `-dealloc`.